# How to login to remote machine using expect?

Tags: expect

I'm using expect to login to remote machine. But i really don't know what exactly this expect is. By googling i got to know about these commands. How to save these scripts & how to execute it ?

```
spawn telnet 10.123.9.111
expect login {send username\r}
expect password {send password\r}
```

is this correct ? Suggestion to improve this script most welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this to a file `telnet.exp`:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 10.123.9.111
expect login {send username\r}
expect password {send password\r}
interact  ;# I assume you want to do something on the remote machine here
```

Make it executable: `chmod 700 telnet.exp` -- you want to use restrictive permissions since you're storing your password in a plain-text file which is not a good idea (you should be using ssh with keys unless the device cannot run ssh)

Run it: `./telnet.exp`

If you want to be able to pass variables to your script:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
lassign $argv ip user passwd
spawn telnet $ip
expect login {send $user\r}
expect password {send $passwd\r}
interact  ;# I assume you want to do something on the remote machine here
```

Run it: `./telnet.exp 10.123.9.111 username secret`

This is bad too because now the password will show up in a `ps` listing.

Comment: @ Glenn : How can i execute it on windows ?